# Function expression parameters with the same name than the outer function declaration parameters

Tags: javascript

I want to manually create the function below and I want there to be a parameter with the same name in both the function and the `foreach` inside. The snippet works, but

Is there any way for it to work by setting `elem < this.elem` instead of `elem < arguments [0]`, or referencing the outer `elem` without `arguments[0]`?

```
function anyElemMinorThan(elem, arr) {
  let found = false;
  arr.forEach(elem => {
   if (elem < arguments[0]) found=true;
  });
  return found;
}
```

Comment: [`arr.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would be a better choice than forEach. In your case if the option was the first item, you end up looping over every other item which is a waste of time. Some would just exit when it is found.

Comment: Choose different names and avoid the whole `arguments[0]` or `this.elem` problem. Since you need both to be available inside the loop scope, I don't see a good reason to give both variables the same name.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, it's a function sample, the idea is if there is any way to not use arguments[0] in this example case.

Comment: Thanks @Shilly, I'm afraid that, but I'd like to use the same name and both are available in the loop.

Comment: Asking for the "best" way of doing something, without specifying parameters for what is "best" invites opinions, so I've removed that part of the question. Also, answers to the question will naturally be voted up if they have a better implementation.

Comment: *"if there is any way to not use arguments[0]"* Yes, use different variable names...

Answer (score 0):

1) probably not, in this case shorter is better (as it is more performant + readable):

```
  const anyElemMinorThan = (elem, arr) =>
     arr.some(val => val < elem);
```

or if you prefer imperative style:

```
  function anyElemMinorThan(elem, arr) {
   for(const val of arr)
     if(val < elem)
       return true;
    return false;
  }
```

2) just rename one of the `elem` variables to some other name?